# Combine array items in Azure Logic App Consumption

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an output of http action which contains an array of objects and looks like this:

```
[
{
"Id":1,
"Good":0,
"Average":0,
"Bad":1
},
{
"Id":2,
"Good":1,
"Average":0,
"Bad":0
},
{
"Id":1,
"Good":0,
"Average":1,
"Bad":0
},
{
"Id":3,
"Good":0,
"Average":0,
"Bad":1
},
{
"Id":1,
"Good":0,
"Average":1,
"Bad":0
},
]
```

How can i combine them to get this result without using inline javascript, using dataoperation action? Basically i need to sum records` values, and combine by ID

```
[
{
"Id":1,
"Good":0,
"Average":2,
"Bad":1
},
{
"Id":2,
"Good":1,
"Average":0,
"Bad":0
},
{
"Id":3,
"Good":0,
"Average":1,
"Bad":0
}
]
```

Comment: There’s an aggregate function in the Advanced Data Operations connector … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/#aggregate … it’s quite affordable too.

Comment: @Skin i think it`s available only for standard logic apps

Comment: No, it’s consumption. You just need to sign up for a trial … https://www.statesolutions.com.au/pricing/

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to achieve what you're wanting by using the **Aggregate** operation in the **Advanced Data Operations** connector.

This is your data configured to `SUM` the `Good`, `Average` and `Bad` properties by the `Id` field.

[image: Flow]

**Output**

[image: Output]

#### Result

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Good": 0,
    "Average": 2,
    "Bad": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Good": 1,
    "Average": 0,
    "Bad": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Good": 0,
    "Average": 0,
    "Bad": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Looks indeed very powerful, thanks, i will put this one in bookmarks. Unfortunately i am limited with build-in actions in this case :(

Comment: That's a shame because doing what you want in the flow will be a pain in the butt without the use of this connector.  This operation makes it hell easy.  You could do it using XML but you'll need to fashion up an XLST I'd say and that will require an integration account, etc.  A bit more work than what I've shown you.  Good luck anyway.